# exc_breakpoint while JSON parsing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I want to parse many JSON strings. Here is the code:

```
while(stations.count > 0) {
        NSString*string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[stations objectAtIndex:0]] retain];
        
        NSMutableDictionary*dic = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]retain];
        
        NSData*data = [[[NSData alloc] initWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]retain];
        NSMutableDictionary* pars = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil]];
        
        [dic setObject:[NSString stringWithString:[pars objectForKey:@"nm"]] forKey:@"nm"];
        [dic setObject:[NSString stringWithString:[pars objectForKey:@"btr"]] forKey:@"btr"];
        [dic setObject:[NSString stringWithString:[pars objectForKey:@"id"]] forKey:@"id"];
        [dic setObject:[NSString stringWithString:[pars objectForKey:@"cntr"]] forKey:@"cntr"];
        [dic setObject:[NSString stringWithString:[pars objectForKey:@"gnr"]] forKey:@"gnr"];
        
        [pars release];
        @try {
            [parsedData addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dic]];
        }
        @catch (NSException* exc) {
            NSLog(@"%@, %@", exc.description, exc.reason);
        }
        [dic release];
        [data release];
        [string release];
        [stations removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        
        if (i%1000==0) {
            NSLog(@"nnnn %i %i", parsedData.count, stations.count);
        }
        
        i++;
        float k = count;
        k = (i + 1)/k;
        
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(increaseProgress:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:k] waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
```

On adding (usually but not every time) string to array I get error:

> exc_breakpoint (code=exc_i386_bpt

and:

> GuardMalloc[Radiocent new try-1820]: Failed to VM allocate 68752 bytes
>
> GuardMalloc[Radiocent new try-1820]: Explicitly trapping into debugger!!!

Stations array is pretty big... about 60000 strings.

Comment: Why are you using stringWithString?  It's just wasted motion that makes the code harder to read.

Comment: Mmm, that's my probelm with good style, I thought it helps to avoid problems with memory managment. My bad...

Comment: The only reason to use stringWithString is if the source string might be a mutable string, and your logic would be rendered unstable/vulnerable if it were.  This is a very rare situation.

Comment: (But at least you didn't use `stringWithFormat:@"%@"` -- that's a lot more wasted motion.)

Comment: Thx for advices. I thought, if I release source string is affects on my new sttring.

Comment: You need to understand iOS storage management a bit better.  In particular, NSStrings (of the non-Mutable variety) are invariant, so, in fact, `stringWithString` is likely a no-op -- just passing through the original if it's not Mutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all when you alloc you don't need to retain as retain count is already +1.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Not

```
NSMutableDictionary*dic = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]retain];
```

Below line already returs mutable dictionary so you don't have to create a new dictionary out of that and if you want to change then just call a - mutableCopy on it.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

or to create a copy:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

If stations is JSON string then for all stations do this:

```
NSData *data = [JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *stationsArray = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil] mutableCopy];

for (NSDictionary *stationDic in stationArray)
{
     // This will iterate over each station dictionary in the station array
     // Do your stuff here ...
}
```

For your example: (I have added \" to escape the double quotes, you don't have to)

Placed square brackets around your example this make it an array and you can iterate through each using the given code below. (Add only if they are not there)

```
NSString *example = @"[{\"id\":\"02AB99\",\"btr\":\"24\",\"cntr\":\"461E\",\"gnr\":\"8A51\",\"nm\":\"88.3 Fm Radio Q Jogjakarta\"}, {\"id\":\"026058\",\"btr\":\"160\",\"cntr\":\"461E\",\"gnr\":\"8A7B\",\"nm\":\"88.3 The Dog\"}, {\"id\":\"0300D2\",\"btr\":\"55 64\",\"cntr\":\"461C\",\"gnr\":\"8A75\",\"nm\":\"88.3 The Wind\"}, {\"id\":\"0159E6\",\"btr\":\"128\",\"cntr\":\"4610\",\"gnr\":\"8A6C\",\"nm\":\"88.30 Z Fm Radio Word Online\"}]";

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *stationArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[example dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

if (!error)
{
    for (NSDictionary *stationDic in stationArray)
    {
        NSLog(@"\nName: %@ \nDump: \n%@", [stationDic valueForKey:@"nm"], stationDic);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot! Memory management is hard for me.
About stations, it is not JSON string, but every object in this array is.

Comment: Can you share with me an example so i can answer appropriately.

Comment: Ok.

`{"id":"02AB99","btr":"24","cntr":"461E","gnr":"8A51","nm":"88.3 Fm Radio Q Jogjakarta"},

{"id":"026058","btr":"160","cntr":"461E","gnr":"8A7B","nm":"88.3 The Dog"},

{"id":"0300D2","btr":"55 64","cntr":"461C","gnr":"8A75","nm":"88.3 The Wind"},

{"id":"0159E6","btr":"128","cntr":"4610","gnr":"8A6C","nm":"88.30 Z Fm Radio Word Online"}`

And I have 60 000 objects like this.

Comment: @Lager - That looks like a JSON array to me.

Comment: It's like JSON array, but without "[ ... ]". So from server I get only data with dictionaries {...} separated by "\n".

Comment: @Lager Yes and if u can change the server response than add that there else add "[ ... ]" and you are good to iterate over each entry. They are separated by comma. `{"id":"02AB99","btr":"24","cntr":"461E","gnr":"8A51","nm":"88.3 Fm Radio Q Jogjakarta"}` This is one dictionary.

Comment: Nop, I can't do that. It is not my decision.

Comment: @Lager Then i guess you have to do that at your end and you can do it like my sample code.

Comment: @SAPLogix Yes, I'll try to do this.